# Как создать грид в ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, база-данных, mvc, razor

Необходимо вывести таблицу в mvc, в дальнейшем реализовать фильтрацию. В mvc новичок, потому применил первое найденное решение. На данный момент, вывод таблицы таков:

```html
@using MvcSaleProject.Models
<h2>Full information about sales</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Client
        </th>
        <th>
            Goods
        </th>
        <th>
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>
    @using (UsersContext dataBase = new UsersContext())
    {
        foreach (var i in dataBase.Archive)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelUser => i.SaleId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelUser => i.Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelUser => i.Client)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelUser => i.Goods)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelUser => i.Amount)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    }
    
    

</table>
```

Однако данный вывод мне не нравится, посоветуйте как выводить таблицу в mvc, желательно увидеть какие-нибудь примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MVC в отличии от WebForms нет какого-то большого набора контролов, предполагается, что вы используете какой-нибудь сторонний фреймворк на клиенте, допустим bootstrap для стилей, JQuery для js.
Я вот этот плагин для jquery использовал https://www.datatables.net/
Либо посмотрите другие популярные js фреймворки.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Можете посмотреть в сторону jqGrid http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/jqgrid-asp-net-mvc